# Sencilla aplicación con Android - Java , no guarda en DB

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, sqlite

Tengo una consulta, estoy haciendo una aplicación que guarde datos, pero al dar clic en guardar se cierra la app, creo que  tiene que ver con la bd porque cuando le quito

```
dataBaseWorks.guardaDatos(work,date,description);
```

de la newWork.java si no se cierra; pero obviamente ya no guarda

DataBaseWorks.java :

```
public class DataBaseWorks extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="Works.db";

public DataBaseWorks (Context context){
    super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);


}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Tarea (" +
            "id_tarea INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "fecha VARCHAR NOT NULL, " +
            "nombre VARCHAR NOT NULL, " +
            "descripcion VARCHAR NOT NULL);");

}

   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }


public void guardaDatos(String work, String date, String desc){
    getReadableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO Tarea VALUES('+null+','"+work+"','"+date+"','"+desc+"')");
}

public Cursor getTareas(){
    return getReadableDatabase().query("Tarea",null,null,null,null,null,null); 
}

}
```

Esta es la New Work:

```
 public class NewWorkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView back;
ArrayList <String> tarea, fecha, desc;
EditText etTarea, etDia, etMes, etAnio, etDesc;
LinearLayout btnGuardar;
Work objWork;
DataBaseWorks dataBaseWorks;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_work);
dataBaseWorks = new DataBaseWorks(this);

tarea= new ArrayList<String>();
fecha= new ArrayList<String>();
desc= new ArrayList<String>();

etTarea= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
etDia= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_dia);
etMes= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mes);
etAnio= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_anio);
etDesc= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_desc);

btnGuardar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn_guardar);
back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backanw);


btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        guardarDatos();

    }
});

back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
   }



 public void guardarDatos() {

String date;
String work;
String description;


work= etTarea.getText().toString();
date =etDia.getText().toString() + "/" + etMes.getText().toString() + "/" + 
etAnio.getText().toString();
description=etDesc.getText().toString();


dataBaseWorks.guardaDatos(work,date,description);

Toast.makeText(this,"la atrea se ha agrgado correctamente", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
finish();


}
}
```

Comment: este es el new Work actovyti:

Comment: Agrega en el insert los campos a excepción de `id_tarea` que es autoincrementable y no debe ir en el insert.

Comment: Es importante lo que dice @bicho si lo vas a hacer con el método `execSQL()` porque al realizarlo a tu forma también se me caía la app. Por eso propuse el método `insert()` de la API de Android, que es el que estoy acostumbrado a utilizar. Muchas Gracias por el aporte @bicho

Comment: Gracias eso es lo correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu script de creación de tabla, el campo `id_tarea` esta definido como una llave primaria autoincrementable por lo tanto no debes insertarlo, unicamente los demas campos.

```
"INSERT INTO Tarea (nombre, fecha, descripcion)  VALUES('"+work+"','"+date+"','"+desc+"')"
```

Este seria el metodo `guardaDatos()` con el cambio

```
public void guardaDatos(String work, String date, String desc){
    getReadableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO Tarea (nombre, fecha, descripcion)  VALUES('"+work+"','"+date+"','"+desc+"')");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes cambiar el método `getReadableDatabase()` por el método `getWritableDatabase()` porque vas a modificar la tabla. Quedaría de esta forma:

```
public void guardaDatos(String work, String date, String desc){
    getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO Tarea VALUES('+null+','"+work+"','"+date+"','"+desc+"')");
```

}

También puedes utilizar la API de Android para insertar los valores de la siguiente manera:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("fecha", date);
values.put("nombre", work);
values.put("descripcion", description);
values.put("favorite", 0);
getWritableDatabase().insert("tarea", null, values);
```